# Razor Syntax DropDownListFor not showing selected item when bootstrapped

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having an odd problem.
I have this code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"))
```

and it works perfectly.  Model.Genre pulls values from my db, displays them and I can select one fine.

However, when I try to boot strap it and add this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It still pulls the values for the list, but whenever I select one it no longer displays it as being selected! The binding still does work, because if I save the form it saves correctly.  It looks pretty now, but the displaying does not work.

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had padding on my .form-control like such

```
.form-control {
font-size: 17px;
padding: 20px 15px;
border-radius: 9px;
}
```

removing the padding and adding a height fixed this issue.

```
.form-control {
font-size: 17px;
border-radius: 9px;
height: 44px;
}
```